# Slick joinLeft syntax with postgres

Tags: postgresql, playframework, slick

Sorry but i'm still newbie and i don't how to get data from student_table that doesn't exist on contact_table.

my code is like this:

```
def leftJoin (id: Int): Future[Seq[Student]] = {
  db.run((contact.query(id) joinLeft student.query on (_.contactId === _.studentId)).result)
}
```